# AWS EBS references

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Perhaps this isn't so much a code question as a definitional question, but would someone be able to explain to me what the six line items below represent?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EBS has 3 types of storage (in order from most expensive to cheapest):

- Provisioned I/O. These are SSD volumes with a performance guarantee. With these volumes you not only pay for the size of the volume, but also the number of IOPS you have provisioned. These volumes should only be used when performance is very important.
- General Purpose SSD. These volumes provide improved performance over Magnetic volumes at a somewhat higher cost. Probably the best choice for most general purpose uses.
- Magnetic. This type of storage uses magnetic disks and is the cheapest and slowest. Good for bulk data storage that doesn't have any performance requirement.

The other two items not covered by the above volume types are IO requests, which occur any time data blocks are read or written to any volume. Also snapshots are copies of volumes stored on S3.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Elastic Block Storage is offered in three flavors: Magnetic, PIOPS SSD and General Purpose SSD.

Each flavor will offer different performance and prices, that you can check in the [EBS pricing page](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/).

These lines looks like a budget showing how much of each is consumed by your project :)